# log scale error in r during barplot

Tags: r

I have to plot a barplot in R. Following is the data

```
mime_doc$FREQ_PCNT
[1] 97.89  10.19  1.34  3.50  5.01  0.02  0.00  0.04
> mime_doc$BYTE_PCNT
[1] 90.72  19.82  0.70  5.64  0.05  0.04  0.01  0.01
```

And following are the commands for barplot

```
mime_freq = data.frame(mime_doc$FREQ_PCNT, mime_doc$BYTE_PCNT)
barplot(t(mime_freq), beside = TRUE, col = c('blue','red') log = 'y')
```

It gives following error

```
Error in barplot.default(mime_doc$FREQ_PCNT, beside = TRUE, col = c("blue",  : 
  log scale error: at least one 'height + offset' value <= 0
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seventh value of `mime_doc$FREQ_PCNT` is zero, so doesn't make sense to plot on a log scale. You can deal with this in a couple of ways.

## Replace it with NA

`mime_doc<- data.frame(FREQ_PCNT=c(97.89,  10.19,  1.34,  3.50,  5.01,  0.02,  NA,  0.04), 
                       BYTE_PCNT=c(90.72,  19.82,  0.70,  5.64,  0.05,  0.04,  0.01 , 0.01))
mime_freq = data.frame(mime_doc$FREQ_PCNT, mime_doc$BYTE_PCNT)
barplot(t(mime_freq), beside = TRUE, col = c('blue','red'), log = 'y')`

Now you get no bar for the value of zero, which seems the most sensible way to visualise it, but that may depend on what you're trying to convey with the plot.

## Use an offset

`mime_doc<- data.frame(FREQ_PCNT=c(97.89,  10.19,  1.34,  3.50,  5.01,  0.02,  0.00,  0.04), 
                       BYTE_PCNT=c(90.72,  19.82,  0.70,  5.64,  0.05,  0.04,  0.01 , 0.01))
mime_freq = data.frame(mime_doc$FREQ_PCNT, mime_doc$BYTE_PCNT)
barplot(t(mime_freq), beside = TRUE, col = c('blue','red'), log = 'y', offset=0.0001)`

The disadvantage of this approach is that the choice of offset is arbitrary and makes a difference to the overall scaling of the plot. The offset should be much less than the minimum non-zero value to avoid distorting the graph.

See `?boxplot` for how the offset works

Comment: Warning about solution with NA - if you want to stack the values this won't work as every component after the first NA will be disregarded.